# Decompress base64 encoded, gzipped JSON

Tags: java, sql, base64, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I've got base64 encoded, gzipped json in a Snowflake binary column that I'm trying to unpack.

With the query:

```
select
    base64_encode(my_binary_data) as my_base64_string
from my_table
```

I  get a base64 encoded string, which I can cut n' paste into a bash script and pipe through:

```
echo $my_base64_string | base64 -d | gunzip
```

and get valid results.  My question is, can I accomplish this through a query?  I've tried some variations with `decompress_string()`, but I can't figure it out.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't `BASE64_DECODE_STRING` do what you want?

Comment: Thanks @endo64. That produces an ```Invalid UTF8 detected while decoding``` error on strings that work in bash.  Obviously I'm using bash as a sanity check here, but there could be a few things I'm overlooking.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've also been able to unpack the json with a similar process in Python.  So as far as `snowflake-sql` I can't tell if I don't know what I'm doing or it's not possible.

Comment: The Snowflake uncompress function has the same available compression/decompression methods as the compress function. In the documentation for compress, it does not list gunzip: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-tabular-functions.html. You'd have to use something external or a Java UDF with a gunzip library in the JAR file.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I'll look into your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```sql
select udf_unzip('H4sIAH4TZWEAA8tIzcnJ5wIAIDA6NgYAAAA=');

-- hello
```

if you define a Java UDF like this:

```sql
create or replace function udf_unzip(b64 string)
returns string
language java
handler='MyClass.unzip'
as
$$
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.io.*;

    class MyClass {
        public static String unzip(String b64) throws Exception {
            byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64);
            GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gis);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
            return in.readLine();
        }
    }
$$;
```

Note that this sample UDF only returns the first line from the encoded string. You'll need to iterate over the BufferedReader to get the whole string:

- [How do I read / convert an InputStream into a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Note that the maximum size for a Java UDF output row is 16 MB according to [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/java/udf-java-introduction.html) so if your entire uncompressed string size exceeds 16MB, you can't iterate over the BufferedReader to get the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Python UDF as follows:

```
create or replace function python_udf_unzip(s string)
returns string
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
handler = 'udf_unzip'
as
$$
def udf_unzip(x):
    import gzip
    import base64
     
    x = gzip.decompress(base64.b64decode(x)).decode('utf-8')
     
    return x
$$;
```

And you can call it as:

```
select python_udf_unzip('H4sIAH4TZWEAA8tIzcnJ5wIAIDA6NgYAAAA=')
```

And you get:

```
hello
```